how do people do VOR airborne check on KOCF?
Georgia has one VOR receiver check point, which is Vienna. The chart supplement says:
Vienna (Crisp County-Cordele) 116.5/VNE A/1300 Radial 226 19NM, with check point description stating over the center of NE/SW runway. I looked up in the aeronautical chart and I found the checkpoint description matches Runway 06-24 at KCKF as well as its traffic pattern alt 1300!!!
SO, here is my question. Do people really fly to KCFK and get in the patter to check VOR while airborne?


You are totally correct. Just fly the pattern and have a look at your instruments when overhead.
Have a look at 14 CFR 91.171(b)(3) for some regulatory background:

If neither a test signal nor a designated checkpoint on the surface is available, use an airborne checkpoint […] (the maximum permissible bearing error is plus or minus 6 degrees);

